OpenTelemetry collector log http setting not working
I set the hotel settings to metric, trace to grpc, and log to http. Metric, trace is collected well, but log gets the following error. Please help
grpc@v1.68.1/clientconn.go:1384 [core] [Channel #4 SubChannel #5]grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {Addr: "loki:3100", ServerName: "loki:3100", }. Err: connection error: desc = "error reading server preface: http2: frame too large"   {"grpc_log": true}


service server
   - OTEL_LOGS_EXPORTER=otlp
   - OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_LOGS_PROTOCOL=http/protobuf
   - OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_LOGS_ENDPOINT=http://collector:4318/v1/logs


monitoring


    receivers:
      otlp:
        protocols:
          http:
            endpoint: collector:4318  
          grpc:
            endpoint: collector:4319  
      prometheus:
        config:
          scrape_configs:
            - job_name: "b2c-service-metric-otel"
              scrape_interval: 5s
              metrics_path: "/actuator/prometheus"
              static_configs:
                - targets:
                    - "b2c-service:8081"

    processors:
      batch:
        timeout: 30s

    exporters:
      debug:
        verbosity: detailed
      otlp/tempo:
        endpoint: tempo:4317 
        compression: "gzip"
        tls:
          insecure: true 
      otlp/loki:
        #endpoint: loki:3100 
        endpoint: loki:3100 
        #endpoint: "grpc://loki:3100"  
        compression: "gzip"
        tls:
          insecure: true

    service:
      pipelines:
        metrics: 
          receivers: [ otlp ]  
          processors: [ batch ]
          exporters: [ debug ]  
        traces:
          receivers: [otlp]
          processors: [batch]
          exporters: [otlp/tempo, debug]
        logs:
          receivers: [otlp]
          processors: [batch]
          exporters: [otlp/loki, debug]



Your OTEL collector is sending too large requests.
It looks like you have long batching:
   processors:
      batch:
        timeout: 30s

Customize your batching so it sends batches more often (I guess the default is 200ms) and/or set maximum batch sizes. Your target is not to hit your Loki limit (check your Loki config/doc to find the exact limit size)
